# Node JS:how can i configure Cluster in sails JS for scaling my app

Tags: node.js, multithreading, express, sails.js, cluster-computing

i am working on sailsJS.
since the node app runs on single thread i need to make cluster of instances using nodeJS's cluster.
but i dont what to do in sails to achieve the cluster thing.
in express it is:

```
    var cluster = require('cluster')
    ,app = require('express')()
    ,numWorkers = require('os').cpus().length;

if(cluster.isMaster) {
    console.log('Master cluster setting up ' + numWorkers + ' workers...');
    for(var i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++)
        cluster.fork();
    cluster.on('online', function(worker) {
        console.log('Worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' is online');
    });
    cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
        console.log('Worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died with code: ' + code + ', and signal: ' + signal);
        console.log('Starting a new worker');
        cluster.fork();
    });
} else {
    app.all('/*', function(req, res) {res.send('process ' + process.pid + ' says hello!').end();})
    var server = app.listen(8000, function() {
        console.log('Process ' + process.pid + ' is listening to all incoming requests');
    });
}
```

but in sails what should i do.
And if i use pm2 to create maximum instances then this happens as in image.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you consider using process managers like pm2 or something?

Comment: pm2 start app.js -i 0
it says app-0 (err): debug: --------------------------------------------------------

and more for other 3 worker processes.
and at browser's console it gives WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:1337/socket.io/?__sails_io_sdk_version=0.11.0&__sails_io_sdk_platform=browser&__sails_io_sdk_language=javascript&EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=pOCOMUS3tkXrFCm_AAEn' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

and sometimes fails to load javascripts and other required dependencies!

Comment: Well, I don't know how to help you. I was hosting sails up with pm2 and everything was fine. I didn't use web socket thought

Comment: Did you add additional configurations to sailsjs? Usually using pm2 doesn't give out any error.

Comment: No.There is no additional confiiguration....Using pm2 i find some other errors in pm2 logs.
i have added the screenshot!

Comment: I think that some app is using the same port 1337. Are you by any chance using sudo on pm2?

Comment: yeah i got that.
please take a look at first screenshot. @mateeyow